# Difference Horizontal Spacing in Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to implement the UI like the below image.

[image]

I layout the UI using GridView and I got only the result like the below image with the same horizontal spacing.

[image]

I would like to know that does Android GridView support difference spacing size between grid item? If there is any solution or third party lib, please help. Thank you. Sorry for my poor in english.

Edit:

According to sgadde and Gary Bak's answers, I calculate and add right margin to items in second column in adapter's getView method with the following code.

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
        viewHolder.numberTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and I got the following result.

[image]

My code to add margin of grid item shrinked the size of grid item. Is something wrong? Please help how to add spacing. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use two gridview? Dear Bus.

Comment: @HeinHtetAung,  I think two GridView is complicated in controlling the number to show. Now, I did it with add object with null value for blank space.

Comment: @BusCar can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate and add right margin to items in second column, left margin to items in third column dynamically. You can do it in getView() of your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter's getView method you have the position, when you hit the position for 2, 6, 10, etc.. then you can add addition spacing on the right.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be a little tricky.

First you need to reduce horizontalSpacing to adjust to be square.

Now, you need to add margin for all columns.

There is four columns, and so

```
column 1: left margin

column 2: right margin

column 3: left margin

column 4: right margin
```

This will be like what you want.